# Why Openlayers z-Index doesn`t put zIndex 16 over zIndex -1

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I'm using Ol 4.6.5 and I have a mistake:

```js
 const geoVector = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJSON)
});

const tilesStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  zIndex: -1,
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: "rgb(53,198,234, 0.8)",
    width: 6
  })
});

this.panoramasTracksLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: geoVector,
  style: tilesStyle
});
map.addLayer(this.panoramasTracksLayer);
```

Here I fetch GEOJSON layer from server

```js
  feature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(point as any)));
  feature.setStyle([
    new ol.style.Style({
      zIndex: 15,
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 20,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: "#fff",
          width: 2
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: "rgb(53,198,234)"
        })
      })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      zIndex: 16,
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: "\u27A4",
        textAlign: "center",
        textBaseline: "middle",
        font: "bold 24px",
        scale: 2.7,
        rotateWithView: true,
        rotation: -1.6 + pRotation,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: "#111"
        })
      })
    })
  ]);
  source.addFeature(feature);
```

And above I add a feature to my map. Why openLayers is painting my panoramasTracks over my features? And how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just a clue: you are mixing zIndex at feature level (`feature.setStyle`) and at layer level (`style: tilesStyle`). Why? Qurestion related to comparison with http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-z-index.html sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Z-index on the layer itself

```js
this.panoramasTracksLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: geoVector,
  style: tilesStyle,
  zIndex: -1
});
```